# 公開しているWEBサイトのjavascriptコードを絶対に見られないようにする方法

Tags: javascript

自分が公開しているWEBサイトのjavascriptコードを絶対に見られないようにする方法ってありますか？
もし、無いとしたら今後そういった技術が現れることはあると思いますか？
何故現状はそういったことが難しいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 無いとしたら今後そういった技術が現れることはあると思いますか？

[WebAssembly](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAssembly)という技術が登場しています。[Firefox、Chromeではすでに利用可能](http://caniuse.com/#feat=wasm)です。バイナリが見られてしまうことは防ぐことができませんし、ある程度は推測されますが、元のソースコードに復元することは困難です。
現状のWindowsアプリケーションと同等ぐらいにお考え下さい。

Answer (score 0):

> 自分が公開しているWEBサイトのjavascriptコードを絶対に見られないようにする方法ってありますか？

ありません。

> もし、無いとしたら今後そういった技術が現れることはあると思いますか？

無いと思います。

> 何故現状はそういったことが難しいのでしょうか？

1. ブラウザを使う側、強いては作る側にそれを可能にする利点が無いから
2. 現状大半のブラウザがサポートしているのがJavaScriptのみで、実行できる以上1度はJavaScriptで表現しないといけないのから
3. JavaScriptに限らずとも、パソコンが実行できる以上、バイナリであれ、元のソースの大雑把なアルゴリズムは復元できるので、**絶対にコードが見られない**ようにする方法はありえません。

ちなみに、オリジナルのソースコード(変数名やループの種類)がわからない程度で良いならUglifyなどがありますが、同じ結果を出すソースである以上、コードが見られ無いかと言われると見えてるのとそう大差は無いです。